# $I = \exp(-\int\frac{\cos t }{\sin t}dt)$ Help please

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$I = \exp(-\int\frac{\cos t}{\sin t}dt)$$

$$I = \exp(-\int\frac{1}{\sin t}\cos tdt)$$

$$I = \exp(-\int\frac{1}{\sin^2 t}dt)$$

$$I = \exp(-\ln|\sin^2t|)$$

$$I = \sin t$$

but answer should be $$\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sin t}}$$

what did I do wrong?

Comment: yes It should be, I'll fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does $\frac 1{\sin t} \cos t$ become $\frac 1{\sin^2 t}$??

$-\int \frac {\cos t}{\sin t} dt\\
u = \sin t\\
du = \cos t\\
-\int \frac 1u du\\
-\ln u\\
-\ln \sin t\\
\ln (\sin t)^{-1}\\
\ln\frac {1}{\sin t}\\
e^{\ln\frac {1}{\sin t}} = \frac {1}{\sin t}$

Comment: $cost=\frac{1}{sint}$

Comment: @Reboot Where did you hear *that*? That is very false.

Comment: $\csc t = \frac 1{\sin t}$

Comment: My apologies, I used the wrong identity. Thanks for awesome explanation

Answer (score 1):

The mistake lies on the third step 
$I = exp(-\int \dfrac{\cos t}{\sin t} d t $
From $u$-substition let $u = \sin t$ then $d u = \cos t d t$ hence we have
$I = exp(-\int\dfrac{d u}{u} = exp(-\ln u) = \dfrac{1}{u} = \dfrac{1}{\sin t}$

Answer (score 1):

May be this direct formula helps you

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\ln\lvert{f(x)}\rvert+c$$